# Sending soap request with X509 Certificate that uses sha256 signing algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, api, x509, x509certificate2

I'm trying to make a soap service.

To send request I need to use X509 Certificate. I used **X509Certificate2** class for that purpose.

The problem is that its keys are **System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider** class that accepts only **"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"** signature algorithm.
In our case sha256 signature algorithm is needed.

Have you got any idea how can I deal with that?

Code looks like this:

```
        SoapService.GetOrderStatusRequest request = new SoapService.GetOrderStatusRequest()
        {
            orderId = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text),
            requestHeader = new SoapService.RequestHeader() 
            { 
                 institutionId = 123, 
                 requestId = "aeacbff8-ba6d-4a01-8e76-0b4384c24721", 
                 system = "Test" 
            }
        };
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//cert.p12", "Passs123");

        client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

        SoapService.GetOrderStatusResponse response = client.getOrderStatus(request);
        txtResult.Text = response.order.name;
```

**Edit1.**
I found out this is not problem with X509Certificate2 configuration, but with binding configuration... with message security to be exac.

Unfortunately I still have some errors :/